# Can Power BI able to get the average weekly percentage per month using DAX / New measure?

Tags: powerbi, dax, visualization, powerbi-desktop, measure

Checking if there is any method to get the average weekly percentage of the month instead of the total?

**My data:**

[image]

**Expected: get the average percentage by sum up the percentage within the month divide the total week**

[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

**START UPDATE**

```
Percent = 
//individual rows
VAR a = SUM(Table1[Amount])/SUM(Table1[Total])
//total rows
VAR b = SUMX(Table1, Table1[Amount]/Table1[Total])/COUNTROWS(Table1)

RETURN IF(HASONEVALUE(Table1[Week]), a,b)
```

**END UPDATE**

Table looks like this:

[image]

Create a measure:

```
Percent = SUM(Table1[Amount])/SUM(Table1[Total])
```

Add to the field well of a matrix:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks. However, i want to get the average of the percentage calculate: (25%+32%+30%+27%)/4 = 29%, any idea how to get it?

Comment: Isn't that the same. Regardless, I'll update now to show how you can have a different calc on the totals.

Answer (score 1):

1. If you have [Percentage] column:

   Measure = IF(
   HASONEVALUE(Data[Month]),AVERAGEX('Data',[Percentage]),
   AVERAGE(Data[Percentage]))
2. If you do not have [Percentage] column:

   Measure 2 = IF(
   HASONEVALUE(Data[Month]),
   AVERAGEX('Data',SUM(Data[Value1])/SUM(Data[Value2])),
   SUM(Data[Value1])/SUM(Data[Value2]))

Note: I named the table as "Data", you can change the name in these sentences.

[image]